# Link gmail from one doamin to another

Tags: ubuntu, email, gmail, centos-7

Good day!

Currently, we have an existing gmail account linked to a specific *webserver(Ubuntu)*. Now we would like to turn off the server(Ubuntu) since it is very old so every file from it was backed-up and then will be transferred to the newly created *webserver(Centos)*. The domain name and gmail account that would be used will be the same. How do you do this? Another thing that bothers me is will it overwrite the file if I would do this?

The gmail account is like this: **information@domain_name**

Thank you.

Comment: If it doesn't end in `gmail.com` then it's not Gmail... Is this a Google Apps (G Suite) domain? How was the account "linked" in the first place? (because there is no such thing as linking mail to a webserver, in general)

Comment: @grawity We will be using POP3?